# What is the OS inside the Time Capsule?

Tags: time-capsule

What is the OS of the Time Capsule ?

Comment: Are you asking what OS Time Capsule runs or which OS's are compatible with it?

Comment: My question has been edited by someone else, and then by me too. I am asking what OS runs in the Time Capsule. I have asked the modern Oracles — namely Google and Wikipedia —, but they did not say any word about this.

Comment: @NicolasBarbulesco The edit by the otehr person seems to make the question much clearer to me. An OS is no of anything a computer system runs an OS

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The ***AirPort* Time Capsule** (the official name, with my emphasis added on *AirPort* - see below for the reason), runs **NetBSD**, according to the [Examples of use](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NetBSD#Examples_of_use) section for NetBSD on Wikipedia. It cites two sources - one being an answer from superuser.com (not very useful in this case), and another an [article on wifinetnews.com](http://wifinetnews.com/archives/2007/02/airport_extreme_apple_breaks_90_mbps.html), that states:

> A source unconnected with Apple provided convincing proof that the AirPort Extreme uses NetBSD as its embedded operating system...

The AirPort Extreme Base Station, AirPort Express Base Station and the AirPort Time Capsule *all run the same firmware* (that's why the *AirPort* in all the names). This can be seen in the firmware downloads available for these products - it's the same download for all these devices. Of course, nobody has jailbroken these devices yet, so we do not know if or how the installation process chooses specific bits for the underlying hardware. But the OS cannot be different with the same firmware download (it does not make sense for these devices to have such a scheme).

See the recent [AirPort update 7.6.4](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5920) page for understanding the above correlation.

Comment: Actually it's not the same download for all of the devices. If you look at the files the AirPort Utility downloads internally, the firmware for the Express and Extreme are different. The Extreme is ARM-based while the Express's processor uses MIPS. See http://theairportwiki.com

Answer (score 0):

The Time Capsule NAS storage can be accessed from Mac OSX, Windows and most *Nix distributions.

Comment: Thank you, but this does not answer my question.  →  See my comment on my question.